# URL rewriting with nginx

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm not sure how to ask this properly.
I have a nginx + php5 + mysql server running.
I would like to have this working:

```
http://www.example.com/advs/352656
```

The current equivalent is

```
http://www.example.com/advs/adv.php?id=352656
```

On the client side, I want to hide the "adv.php?id=352656" part.
Can someone help me on how to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: `url rewriting` is the keyword you looking for.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't here to write code for you. But as @Rufinus said, you should research url rewriting and give it a shot yourself. If you run into any problems with your code, then you should come back an ask a specific question.

Comment: Ngnix doesn't support htaccess. Because you already added the right keyword as a tag (url rewriting), what have you tried? I think this is a really basic question and you're on the right way.

Comment: I tried this: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/advs/(.*) advs/adv.php?id=$1 [L]. But I thought nginx supported htaccess

Comment: this is apache code, you cant use this on nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename advs-folder to /adv and insert this inside your nginx configurations location / {}

```
rewrite ^/advs/(.*)$ /adv/adv.php?id=$1 last;
```

Comment: It is not working. I've already tried this... :/

Comment: did you restart the webserver?

Comment: oh ok, its because you redirect to the same directory.. rename advs-directory in html folder to /adv and change /advs/adv.php?id=$1 accordingly to /adv/adv.php?id=$1

Comment: my bad, I forgot the first / in the replacement part. many thanks.